# How to find all the permutations of a variable amount of 0's and 1's recursively (without using itertools or random)?

Tags: python, recursion, permutation

I'm trying to produce all permutations of a certain number of numbers (for example, 0s and 1s) for a variable number of positions. I will call the number of numbers `ord` (e.g. `ord=2` for only 0s and 1s; `ord=3` for 0s, 1s, and 2s) and the number of positions `Num`. Hence the number of permutations is `ord**Num`.

Note: I **don't want to use itertools** or any other types of built-in functions. I'm asking this out of curiosity, not just trying to find a solution.

For `ord=2` and `Num=3`, the output, in any order, should be:

```
[[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,1]]
```

This can be accomplished by:

```
ord = 2 
mylist = []

for a in range(ord):
    for b in range(ord):
        for c in range(ord):
            mylist.append([a,b,c])
```

For `ord = 2` and `Num = 4`, the output should be:

```
[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,1,1],[0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,1],[0,1,1,0],[0,1,1,1],[1,0,0,0],[1,0,0,1],[1,0,1,0],[1,0,1,1],[1,1,0,0],[1,1,0,1],[1,1,1,0],[1,1,1,1]]
```

But then I would have to add another nested for loop:

```
ord = 2 
mylist = []

for a in range(ord):
    for b in range(ord):
        for c in range(ord):
            for d in range(ord):
                mylist.append([a,b,c,d])
```

An obvious solution is to add 0s and 1s randomly to a list of length `Num` and then to accept that list if it hasn't already been added to `mylist`, but I want a solution that isn't quite so ridiculous.

This is the closest I've gotten so far to a real solution:

```
def myperms(elem, mylist):
    for i in range(len(elem)-1,-1,-1):
        while (elem[i] + 1) < ord:
            elem = list(elem)
            elem[i] += 1
            if elem not in mylist:
                mylist.append(elem)
        if (elem[i] + 1) >= ord: 
            elem = list(elem)
            elem[i] = 0
    return mylist

Num = 3
ord = 2

TotsNum = ord**Num

mylist = []
elem = [0,]*Num
mylist.append(elem)

print(myperms(elem, mylist))
```

But this only gives:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
```

I've tried calling the function within itself (recursion), but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it properly. Does anyone have any ideas about how to solve it recursively? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use a recursive solution:

```
def get_seq(ord, num):
    val = [0]*num
    N = num
    def recurse(ord, num):
        for i in range(ord):
            val[N - num] = i
            if num > 1:
                yield from recurse(ord, num-1)
            else:
                yield val[:]
    return recurse(ord, num)

print(list(get_seq(2, 4)))
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

For other inputs:

```
>>> list(get_seq(3, 2))
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
```

Comment: Thank you; I am having trouble understanding the code. For an easy example, let's say `ord = 2` and `num = 3`. I see how the function `recurse` would yield `[0,0,0]` and `[0,0,1]`, but after that I don't see how the function continues on to loop back to get `[0,1,0]` because once we hit `num = 1`, how does `num` increase again? Maybe my confusion is due to the use of `yield`...

Comment: Yes, and no. `num` does not increase, it just goes back to the caller state. For example if it started from `n==2`, after yielding a `0` it `yields from ` `recurse(n==1)`, when `recurse(n==1)` has yielded `0 and 1`, it goes back to the caller state, where `n` was `2`. It then finishes up the loop by yielding `1`

Answer (score 0):

Use binary, which consists of 0s and 1s.

```
n = 4
all_permutations = []
for i in range(2**n):
    permutation = []
    string = bin(i)
    string = string.split("0b")[1]
    while len(string) != n:
        string = f"0{string}"
    
    for i in string:
        permutation.append(int(i))

    all_permutations.append(permutation)

print(all_permutations)
```